# How to use shared preferences to change the color of a button on click

Tags: android

Is there a way to change the color of a button in android on click using shared preferences so that it persist the color ?

Comment: You need not use shared preferences for the colour to be persisted.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackOverflow, please take the [tour] and visit the [ask] page. Those kind of question are usually getting a lot of downvotes for a simple reason: we are here to help peoples who are facing problems they can't solve event after trying, we are not here to research stuff and tutorials for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already stored in preferences the color with key as "color", do this:

```
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    int color = preferences.getInt("color", -1);

    Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    if (color >= 0) {
        button.setBackgroundColor(color);
    }
```